# Passing form name to function and loop controls

Tags: vba, forms, function, ms-access

I have a form call Questions
I have a function called LoadQuestions

In the Questions form I have textboxes called WPQ1, WPQ2, WPQ3, WPQ4 etc....

I call the function LoadQuestions using the line:

```
LoadQuestions (Me.Name)
```

My LoadQuestions function code is:

```
Function LoadQuestions(ByVal frm As String)
n = 1   'n is the control number on the form (e.g. WPQ1)
For b = 1 To 6  'b 
Forms!Home!CPQNo = b    

QNUM = DLookup("[QuestionsTbl]", "QuestionTotal", "[Count] > 0") 'Query QuestionTotal gives the total number of questions for the
                                                            'current question set (question set = the value of variable 'b'
On Error Resume Next    'used to catch the instances where there is no value for the DLoopUp to return

    For i = 1 To QNUM       'i is the lower level question number - 1 to Total number of questions from the query

        frm![Controls("WPQ" & n)] = DLookup("[questionText]", "QuestionsTbl", "[NoQuest] = " & b & " And [LowQ] = " & i & "")

        n = n + 1               'add 1 to n as this is the control number which increments by 1 for each control used
    Next i
Next b
End Function
```

I am getting the error

> Qualifier must be a collection

and the code highlighted is the line:

```
![Controls("WPQ" & n)] =
```

My question is how do I reference the control on the form? If I run this code as a SUB in the actual form that is using it (with the code

```
Me.Controls("WPQ" & n) =
```

then it works fine. How do I get it to work in a function?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? You don't need to change anything if you want to change a sub to a function

Comment: I want to reuse the function for different forms where the controls are named the same so need to be able to use s variable for the form name

Comment: That doesn't explain anything...

Comment: The code works as a sub on the form Questions where the line in the code is: `code Controls("WPQ" & n) = ... `code the problem I'm having is that to use it as a function where the name of the form will change I need to pass the name of the form to the function, which I do. However it doesn't actually do anything to the controls on the form. How do I get it to actually put the value from the DLookUp into the controls on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `frm` variable is just a string, not a form. If you want to pass the name of the form, you need to get the appropriate form object before you can use it:

```
Function LoadQuestions(ByVal formName As String)
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Application.Forms(formName)
    n = 1   'n is the control number on the form (e.g. WPQ1)
    For b = 1 To 6  'b 
    Forms!Home!CPQNo = b    

    QNUM = DLookup("[QuestionsTbl]", "QuestionTotal", "[Count] > 0") 'Query QuestionTotal gives the total number of questions for the
                                                                'current question set (question set = the value of variable 'b'
    On Error Resume Next    'used to catch the instances where there is no value for the DLoopUp to return

        For i = 1 To QNUM       'i is the lower level question number - 1 to Total number of questions from the query

            frm.Controls("WPQ" & n) = DLookup("[questionText]", "QuestionsTbl", "[NoQuest] = " & b & " And [LowQ] = " & i & "")

            n = n + 1               'add 1 to n as this is the control number which increments by 1 for each control used
        Next i
    Next b
End Function
```